# Is there an API for google's Find My Device, specifically the ringer?

Tags: automation, lost-phone

My mom loses her phone constantly, and it's a pain to log out of my password manager, log into hers, log into her google account, and ring the phone with Find My Device. Is there an API somewhere so I can do this automatically?